# Same first UV and texture but different second UV in each objects

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm making a book shelf with a lot of books. They have the same material for the covers, and the colour of cover is changed randomly in the node. But I want to put different titles over it in each books with the second UV and texture. I have PNG images for the titles. Is there any way to put them avoiding make different materials for all books?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need different UV Maps for each book cover, if they are similar in size and placement. It's enough to use the *Random* output of the *Object Info node* to mix between a bunch of different book cover textures randomly. There's a commercial [Cycles Random Texture](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/cycles-random-texture-node/) node setup available at the Blender Market (disclaimer, I made it)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos nice node group idea!